# how to compute the variable name of a session scope variable for a repeat control

Tags: xpages, xpages-ssjs

I would like to compute the variable name of a sessionScope variable that I use as the data binding source for a xp:repeat control.

I notice the diamond to compute the variable name is not there. Perhaps it is possible via another way?

Answer (score 0):

In theory it should be. Scoped variables are Maps. A dominoDocument datasource works as an object in the similar way - `document1.myField` runs as `document1.getValue("myField")` and `document1.setValue("myField")`. I know there are ways to bind to a computed field name, I think in a Custom Control, for example, getting a field name passed in would be `document1[#{compositeData.passedField)]`. So a similar process for binding to a scoped variable - `sessionScope[#{myComputedVariable}]` should, in theory, work.

Answer (score 0):

There are 2 approaches, one favored over the other, but the other forced onto you in case the name you have to concatenate strings in order to have the final variable name (as it seems to me since you are speaking of a repeat control):

**EL approach**

```
<xp:repeat value="#{something}" var="whatever">
    <xp:text value="#{sessionScope[whatever]}" />
```

**SSJS approach**

```
<xp:repeat value="#{something}" var="whatever">
    <xp:text value="#{javascript:sessionScope.get('somePrefix' + whatever)}" />
```

Problem of the second approach is that you can't do proper data binding with it if it's an input field, only for display.

If you need proper data binding then I suggest, although inelegant - but I don't have your full picture, a backing bean that concatenates your string so that it can be served through EL ready for use.